# The use of "C'est" and "Ce"

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

I think that “ce” means “this” in English, right?

What does this sentence mean?

> C'est un Italien.

Does it mean that “This is an Italian”?

And, regarding:

> Ce sont des Espagnoles.

Does this sentence mean: “Those are Spanish”?

Comment: In English one would never say *"This is an Italian", but "He is Italian".   If English is not your first language you should avoid to try and understand French translating into English, it seems to confuse you more than it helps you. Looking up for *ce* *c'est* in a dictionary would help.  Try [this page](http://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/cest-versus-il-elle-est).

Comment: Basically, yes. There are subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: while I learned French for a couple years and hopefully have gotten a decent grasp of grammar, it's been a while since I learned French seriously and (as might be guessed) I'm not a native speaker (and do not have the proficiency of one).*

If I remember correctly, `ce` (and the appropriate plural/feminine forms) can mean both `this` or `that` in English, depending on the context. Comparatively, `ceci` and `celà` mean `this` and `that` respectively, but are only used as pronouns, and not as demonstrative adjectives.

Thus, your translations of the sentences into English seems to be correct, although without a more specific context, I would be inclined to read the second as `These [women/girls] are Spanish.` Since the nationality has to be inflected for gender, there is also an implicit piece of information there, although technically speaking "This is an [male] Italian" and "These are Spanish [females]" is still correct. Comparatively, if we had `ces sont des espagnols`, we wouldn't really be able to conclude anything about "these [people]" apart from the fact that "these [people]" contains at least one male.

(Also as a side note: as a native English speaker, I *would* say "this is an Italian", for instance in "This is an Italian. He takes the metro to work every morning and drinks espresso at lunch." While I might not say this much in normal conversation, I would probably use it at the very least in writing, perhaps to achieve a certain style.)

Comment: *Ce sont des Espagnoles* means "These ladies/girls are Spanish." *C'est un Italien.* - notice the full stop at the end of OP's sentence - means "He's Italian".

Comment: @Laure - thanks for pointing that out - I completely missed that earlier. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @Laure: also, isn't saying "this is an Italian" (in the sense of "this [man] is an Italian") technically a reasonable, if slightly awkward translation (depending on context) for "c'est un italien"?

Comment: I would never say "this is an Italian".

Comment: @dangph: I would (as a native English speaker, which I assume counts for something), but mostly within a specific written stylistic context.

Answer (score 2):

as a native French speaker I'll try to explain with more details the correct meanings and translations. Note that I'm not a native English speaker, so I cannot guarantee a 100% my translations :-)

> C'est un Italien.

means in english `This is an Italian`, which is different from:

> Il est Italien

which means `He's Italian`.

> Ce sont des Espagnoles

Means `These are Spanish girls`

In this case, `Ce sont` is identical to `C'est` but is the plural form, used because there are more than one Spanish girl. We know that they are girls because `Espagnoles` has a final `e` (not `Espagnols`).

> These [women/girls] are Spanish

shoud be translated by `Ces femmes/filles sont Epagnoles` which really means `these ones`.

As an example,

> Regarde les filles là bas, ce sont des Epagnoles, mais celles-ci sont Italiennes

should translated by something like `Look at the girls over there, these are Spanish, but those ones are Italians`

Comment: I'd hesitate to translate the stuff in the second half as "those/these ones", but in general I like this explanation.

Comment: Translating is always difficult. Sometimes these is no exact translation :-)

Comment: I'll add that this is the correct use of `C'est/ce sont`, but often, we use `c'est` even if the rest is plural, by mistake, but a lot said/accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The construction is ce, plus a form of etre, "to be."

The third person singular construction is ce est, (he is), which contracts to C'est. C'est un Italien. He is an Italian.

The third person plural construction is Ce sont, (they are) with no contraction. Ce sont des Espagnoles. They are (some) Spaniards.

(Des is a contraction of de and les, and "de" in this context functions as an "adverb of quantity.")